# What are my options for fast transfer of python dictionaries and lists over zeromq sockets using pyzmq?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, serialization, zeromq

I've been using zeromq REQ/REP TCP sockets for communication between threads in my application so that I can easily move from threads to a distributed architecture of multiple machines in the future.

I regularly send large lists of dicts.  By large, I mean lists that are tens to hundreds of thousands dicts long, with dicts being composed of key strings of less than 10 characters and values being strings less than 100 characters and one datetime object.

My issue is that the pickling done by pyzmq's send_pyobj and recv_pyobj is extremely CPU and time intensive to an unworkable degree.

My best current understanding is that this is a serialization problem and not a transport protocol problem so switching to IPC or inproc from TCP shouldn't make any appreciable difference.

Comment: Looks like you are sending quite large data, it's not that surprising that it takes so long. But anyway, I would try a different serialization library, like MessagePack, possibly written in C. But still, it's hundreds of megabytes...

Comment: Inproc would make a huge difference if you could pass pointers around, but that is possible only with lower-level languages like C. Then you are not really copying the data and it's super fast...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [stated in the docs](https://zeromq.github.io/pyzmq/serialization.html) in relation to `send_pyobj` and `recv_pyobj`:

> These methods designed for convenience, not for performance, so
>   developers who do want to emphasize performance should use their own
>   serialized send/recv methods.

Have a look at [how to create your own serialization methods](https://zeromq.github.io/pyzmq/serialization.html#using-your-own-serialization).

You might as well be able to send the data by batches (if you don't really need *all* the data before starting processing it). Sending batches also improves performance as the serialization happens at the same time as the de-serialization.

Comment: Batching the data is exactly what I ended up doing to get acceptable performance, I just never came back and answered my own question.  Shame on me!

Answer (score 1):

For [de]serialization [msgpack](http://msgpack.org/index.html) is a lot faster than pickle.

```
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:09:58) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.3.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

In [1]: import pickle
In [2]: import msgpack
In [3]: import numpy as np
In [4]: xx = [{x: list(np.random.rand(100))} for x in range(10000)]
In [5]: %timeit pickle.dumps(xx)
1 loop, best of 3: 2.6 s per loop
In [6]: %timeit msgpack.packb(xx)
10 loops, best of 3: 38.1 ms per loop
In [7]: msgpack.unpackb(msgpack.packb(xx)) == xx
Out[7]: True
In [8]:
```

So in this case 68x faster.

```
In [22]: xxs = msgpack.packb(xx)
In [23]: xxp = pickle.dumps(xx)
In [25]: %timeit msgpack.unpackb(xxs)
10 loops, best of 3: 24.8 ms per loop
In [26]: %timeit pickle.loads(xxp)
1 loop, best of 3: 280 ms per loop
```

Over 10x faster on deserialization.

You also get the considerable advantage of multi-language option.

Also Pandas has a very fast to and from msgpack implementation if you want to do Numpy arrays.

```
pip install msgpack-python
```